# escape sequences in strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to write this sentence in 3 lines but on scrimba this does not work but on Repl.lt (https://repl.it/repls/WickedBaggyRegression) it works, why?

```
var myStr = 'FirstLine\n\\SecondLine\\\rThirdLine';
console.log(myStr);
```

Comment: *"...scrimba this does not work but on Rep" lt it works,"*  What?

Comment: when i try to write that code in 3 different lines on scrimba site it DOES NOT work, it shows it in one line. but on this site ((https://repl.it/repls/WickedBaggyRegression) it shows it on 3 lines, whyy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the browser console, you can see that the escape characters work perfectly fine. Please don't rely on the inbuilt console of tutorial sites, for the credibility of Javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to how scrimba.com site does interpret and displays your log in its own custom console.
(it probably wrap the text `console.log` receives in a single line.)

Try by replacing `console.log` by `alert` and you will see escape sequences are "preserved" in the alert popup displayed in the simulated browser, which means, they are correct in a JavaScript way :

I also found a course that explain this: https://scrimba.com/p/p4Mrt9/c4vJdha

[image]